# How to embed CSS styling into image base64 code in IONIC3?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, imagefilter

I'm trying to add filters on images via CSS. What I'm trying to do is that first, the user will pick the image from the gallery then that image will be converted into Base64 code and will be stored in a variable and that base64 encoded image will be displayed on the next page by transferring that variable. Now upon the next page, that image will be displayed into different filters of CSS. What I want is that whenever the user clicks on the desired filtered image, the CSS filter will become part of the base64 code and display on the next page where the user can post it.
Thanks

Comment: If you want us to help you, you need to provide us some code containing your progress so far.

Comment: where should i provide the code? I'm new at stack overflow, kindly guide me @GreenAtomic

Comment: You can click the **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51781511/edit)** link to add the code into your post. Then, you can use the **[formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** to display your code properly, such as [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do/358993#358993) for web-related codes.

Comment: If you want to read about it in detail, have a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)